# Pass google search results (from widget) into my webview (Android)

Tags: android, search, webview, widget, android-webview

I have created a `WebView` app for my android device, but I have come to a brick wall. Can anyone help.

I am trying to get Google search  results from the Google search widget, passed into my `Webview` ?. so basically making my `Webview` app the native browser for my phone. is this possible ? can anyone point me in the right direction

(image of Google search widget)

> [image]

I have searched all over the web, but all I can find is,

1. making links stay inside the `Webview`. But I have already done this.
2. How to create a Google query

I have already done these (with succession) all I need to know now is, pass Google widget results 
into my `Webview`. fairly new to app development, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use google Data APIs or GDATA api.
Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/gdata/docs/directory). Select the proper api you need and read its documentation on how to use it.

You can also check the [google api - java client for android](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/) or [gdata -java - client](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/)

The documentation for google web search can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/web-search/docs/).
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thankyou for your quick response, I will have a look into them links later.

Comment: Avoid using comments just for thanks. While I appreciate it, it may get removed and will earn you -ve reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Use this api from google to get results

```
http://google.com/complete/search?output=toolbar&q=football
```